# How to bring the coordinate lines all the way to the axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

How can I bring the coordinate lines all the way to the axis? Here is my code:

```
X, Y = df['xdata'], df['ydata']

xs=[4]
ys=[6.7]
colors=['b']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.scatter(xs, ys, c=colors)

plt.plot(X,Y, marker=' ', markersize=3, linewidth=1, color='black')
plt.xlabel('Anoxic tank volume (m³)', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Effluent TN (mg/L)', fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)

for x, y, c in zip(xs, ys, colors):
    ax.plot([x, x], [0, y], c=c, ls='-.', lw=2.0, alpha=0.5)
    ax.plot([0, x], [y, y], c=c, ls='-.', lw=2.0, alpha=0.5)
    
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Would you prefer to start the axes from 0 or draw the line to the axes?

Comment: This is a good point. I just needed the axes to start from 0 really so should have just asked for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`matplotlib.pyplot.xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html):

```
plt.xlim([0, X.max()])
plt.ylim([0, Y.max()])
```